# Asymptotic distribution of $\sum X_{i}^2$

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, asymptotics

We have $X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}$ as the independent standard normal random variables. Let us define:

$T_{n} = \sum X_{i}^2$ then what will be the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{n}(\frac{T_{n}}{n} - 1)$?

**My approach:**

Since $T_{n}$ is sum of standard normals, it will follow chi-square with $n$ degree of freedom. Hence, we can write:

$E(T_{n}) = n$

$V(T_{n}) = 2n$

It implies that:

$\frac{T_{n} - n}{\sqrt{2n}}$ will follow asymptotic standard normal. Even if I adjust the terms, I am not getting $\sqrt{n}(\frac{T_{n}}{n} - 1)$ for which I need the distribution.

I can probably think of following but I am not sure if it is correct.

Let $P_{n} = \frac{T_{n} - n}{\sqrt{2n}}$. We got that $P_{n}$ follows asymptotic $N(0,1)$. Let us define $C_{n} = \sqrt{2}P_{n}$. Hence, $C_n$ will follow asymptotic $N(0,2)$ and if we expand $C_n$, we will get:

$C_{n} = \sqrt{2}P_{n} = \sqrt{2}\frac{T_{n} - n}{\sqrt{2n}} = \sqrt{n}(\frac{T_{n}}{n} - 1)$. Hence, the required distribution is $N(0,2)$.

Is my approach correct? I am not sure if we can adjust the terms like this asymptotically? I know we can do the same in general when we are not talking in terms of asymptotic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.  (Though you should remove the excessive notation.)  Using the asymptotic approximation (from the central limit theorem) you have:

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{n} \cdot \bigg( \frac{T_n}{n}-1 \bigg) 
&= \sqrt{n} \cdot \frac{T_n-n}{n} \\[6pt]
&= \sqrt{2} \cdot \frac{T_n-n}{\sqrt{2n}} \\[6pt]
&= \sqrt{2} \cdot \frac{T_n - \mathbb{E}(T_n)}{\mathbb{S}(T_n)} \\[8pt]
&\overset{\approx}{\sim} \sqrt{2} \cdot \text{N}(0,1) \\[16pt]
&\sim \text{N}(0,2). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks ben. I will take care of notations from next time.